# B&W image to binary array

Tags: python, image, binary, converters

I want to convert my b&w image(.png) to binary array(black is 1 white is 0). I have written some code, but it's not working. Error says: argument 2 to map() must support iteration. 
Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
from resizeimage import resizeimage
import sys

def threshold(col):
    s = sum(col) 
    return int(s > 255 * 3 // 2)

img = Image.open("filename.png")

ratio = float((img.size[1]) / (img.size[0]))

img = resizeimage.resize_cover(img, [100, int(ratio * 100)])

pixels = img.getdata()
binary = list(map(threshold, img))

array2d = [binary[i * img.size[0] : (i+1) * img.size[0]] for i in range(img.size[1])]
print('\n'.join(''.join(map(str, line)) for line in array2d))
```

Here is the image:

[image: example image]

Comment: actually b&w or are there gray colors?

Comment: no only b&w, image is just I drew a black circle with paint, with white backgound.

Comment: Replace `binary = list(map(threshold, img))` with `binary = list(map(threshold, pixels))`

Comment: still, an empty list I get

Comment: What about converting to a NumPy array with `np_img = np.array(img)`, then setting non-zero values to 1 `np_img[np_img > 0] = 1`

Comment: With that, when I print np_img, I see just 1. And I tried to convert ndarray to list using `np_img.tolist()` , but it's not converting.

Comment: Hmm, can you add your original image to the post?

Comment: I did, you can check it out, its just black circle, that I drew with paint

Comment: Thanks, I see the issue now, check out my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your image to grayscale first, since PIL opens it as RGB. Then, invert the 0 & 255 values. Then, you can convert the non-zero values to 1. Here's one way:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('bw_circle.png').convert('L')

np_img = np.array(img)
np_img = ~np_img  # invert B&W
np_img[np_img > 0] = 1
```

And an alternative way using PIL for the inversion:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('bw_circle.png').convert('L')
img_inverted = ImageOps.invert(img)

np_img = np.array(img_inverted)
np_img[np_img > 0] = 1
```

Comment: I printed np_img [[1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 ...,
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 ..., 1 1 1]]

Comment: instance of 1 i need to print 0 . same for 0 to 1 .How will do that .

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('bw_circle.png').convert('1')
binary = bytes(np.packbits(~np.array(image)))
```